# How to fetch a refcursor in a function returned from another function in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

The mainfunc() returns the refcursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mainfunc()
RETURNS refcursor
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    declare 
    ref1 refcursor;
    BEGIN 
          ref1 = 
          OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT city, pincode FROM employees WHERE id = 1;   
          RETURN ref1;
    end;
    $BODY$
```

The child function is shown below which needs to fetch from the refcursor returned from mainfunc().

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION secondfunc(ref1 refcursor)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
 declare
    rec record;
    sample integer;
    ref1 refcursor;
    begin
    select * from mainFunc() ;
    for rec in ref1
    loop
    fetch next from ref1 into rec;
    exit when not found;
    raise notice 'display %', rec.id;
    end loop;
    end;
    $BODY$;
```

Comment: Why not simply declare `mainfunc()` to `returns tables (...)` and use `for rec in select * from mainfunc()` in the second function?

Comment: This is a sample code, actual implementation needs to fetch a refcursor from another function.